# Apt install hanging/Freezes when trying to run updates with no errors 17.10

Tags: apt, dpkg, 17.10, freeze, aptitude

I've been attempting to update my machine for the past few hours and I can't seem to get it to work.

I ran:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

This found multiple packages for things like updating the linux headers etc. I let it run over night and noticed that it had not made any progress and I could not kill it using ctrl+c.

I closed out the terminal and deleted the locks and ran:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Which also hung. I deleted the locks once more, restarted my machine and now it's hanging at:

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-headers-4.13.0-17-generic (4.13.0-17.20) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.13.0-17-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-17-generic

Progress: [  0%] [..........................................................]
```

I'm totally stumped. How do I get it to install these packages, or where can I search for errors?

Comment: Are you using a nvidia graphics card by any chance?

Comment: I am! And I'm running the Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: Look at this answer ^

Answer (score 0):

For those having this issue - the problem was related to my NVidia drivers - this resolved the problem:

NOTE: Don't be dumb like me. I was like "Oh I'll just go disable them through the GUI Software manager and revert back to the Nouveau drivers temporarily!"

Since DPKG is stuck unable to install the packages - you're machine will never disable the NVidia drivers and if you reboot, you'll get an issue where you have to enter recovery mode - repair DPKG (can just select dpkg from the option and it'll do it automatically - as well as install the hung apps)

THEN - re-enable the NVidia drivers once you boot back into the OS and reboot.

**TL;DR: Only disable the NVidia card through the NVidia control center.**